# Why dosen't this javascript object convert to a C# class object?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a little test bed app, where you give the app a note name, sign, and octave, and it spits out the frequency the note should sound at.

I'm having a problem with a JavaScript object that is sent to a server via AJAX.  However, it does not map at all to the class on the action.

The sender code is a piece of JavaScript:

```
$someContainer.on('click', '.raise-pitch', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $line = $(this).parents('.item-line'),
        // Cache GUI elements for this line.  Not pertinent.

    var data = {
        'model': {
            'NoteName': $noteName.val(),
            'Sign': $noteSign.val(),
            'Octave': $noteOctave.val()
        },
        'steps': 1
    };
    var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("AlterPitch", "Home")',
        data: dataString,
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            // Unimportant things.
        }
    });
});
```

In the `data` object, you can see that I have two things: the `model` and the `steps`.  The steps determines how far we alter the musical note.  I have verified that the values for `note name`, `sign`, and `octave` are making it into the data object.  The `steps` are pre-determined.

The `data` object, however, maps to a ViewModel on the C# side, which looks like this:

```
public class NoteViewModel
{
    public enum NoteSign
    {
        Natural,
        Sharp,
        Flat
    }

    public string NoteName { get; set; }
    public NoteSign Sign { get; set; }
    public int Octave { get; set; }
    public float Frequency { get; set; }

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, float> FrequencyLookup = new Dictionary<string, float>
        {
            {"C", 16.35f},
            {"C#", 17.32f},
            {"D", 18.35f},
            {"D#", 19.45f},
            {"E", 20.60f},
            {"F", 21.83f},
            {"F#", 23.12f},
            {"G", 24.50f},
            {"G#", 25.96f},
            {"A", 27.50f},
            {"A#", 29.14f},
            {"B", 30.87f}
        };

    // Methods...not important for reasons below.
}
```

...which itself is encapsulated in a unique view model:

```
public class AlterPitchViewModel
{
    public NoteViewModel model;
    public int steps;

    public NoteViewModel AlterPitch()
    {
        model.ChangeStep(steps);
        return model;
    }
}
```

...or at least it should.  I set a break point in my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AlterPitch(AlterPitchViewModel model)
{
    return Json(model.AlterPitch(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

...But the model is null, which leads to a `NullReference` exception.

the model isn't serializing to an object that gets sent along in this context.  Obviously I am still doing something wrong.  **Question** is...what?

Comment: Missing a `[HttpPost]` attribute on top of the method?

Comment: @Askolein - That helped.  Still, the 'model' part of the request is coming out weird and causing a 404.

Comment: Have you tried to stringify your object and set request content type to json?

Comment: I looked up stringification and added it.  Updated my code, but am back to the original problem, which is a null model making its way to my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach has worked for me.

**Server Side:**

First, create your ViewModel

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestingViewModel(TestViewModel udata)
{
   // Stuff.
}
```

**Client Side:**

```
function CallTestingViewModel() {

    // We create the javascript object based on the 
    // definition of our C# ViewModel class.
    var udata = {
        Id: 1,
        Description: 'This is a test.'
    };

    // Calling the C# method via AJAX.
    $.when(GenericAjaxCall('Home/TestingViewModel', false, udata)).then(function (result) {
        // do stuff
    });

}


// Return the AJAX call as a Promise Object
function GenericAjaxCall(controllerUrl, async, clientData) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: async,
        url: controllerUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(clientData),
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did try this sort of pattern, but I'm still having problems getting things to the server.  I am trying to use this pattern more, since the Promise pattern seems a little bit more readable and organized - thanks for showing me this!

Comment: What exact error are you getting? Could you please provide info about the Headers and Response that Chrome provides in the Developer Tools?

Comment: I refined my object not have use a nested object, and all my problems went away (and, using the promise object configuration you gave above helped simplify my code.)  Maybe I just can't send nested objects to the server, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your HttpPost Method must have one unique parameter which is your ViewModel. My advice: **create a viewmodel per post WebMethod**.

So here:

```
public class AlterPitchViewModel
{
    public NoteViewModel note { get; set; };
    public int Steps { get; set; };
}
```

And adapt your Javascript accordingly. No need to name your javascript model instance as the parameter in the ASP method -> one object arrives and only one parameter is available so no ambiguity.

Comment: While I agree this is a good architectural decision, I'm still having HTTP 404 issues, which this dosen't resolve.  But, it's an excellent suggestion, thanks!

Comment: 404? This is a Routing problem. Not due to your POST issue.